# Flutter + node js backend

Tags: node.js, flutter

I have been trying to connect my flutter app with a node.js backend to send images and I don't know how to begin to code this. I have a vague idea about writing apis using node.js. My flutter app should take an image using the camera and send it to the backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Starting from Flutter frontend, your can use a package like [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) to pick an image file from your camera or gallery.
2. On backend side if your are using nodejs(using express will be a good option for API) and mongodb(a no-sql dbms), you can create a collection for storing all your images as documents.
   Helper link for express routing : https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html

[mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/) is a good library for nodejs that will make your work a lot easier.

3. Once that's done you can create you own apis which will be inititally hosted on your own computer(localhost) using functions like `app.post()` etc. provided by express. Here you can create a POST request which will take the image file from frontend as **form-data**. Extract the image from the body and store it in your database.

Then you will also need to make a GET request to take that image file from your database and pass it to your frontend.

4. Then using the flutter's inbuilt http functions or using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package, you can extract the images from your database using the API's you made.

Unfortunately I can't explain thing in details in just one answer, so you will have to do a lot of research yourself. Below are some links that will help you if you choose node(express) as backend framework and mongodb as database.

Best example of storing and retrieving images using express and mongo db : https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/2408370

Follows the same technique as above but explains what he's doing : https://medium.com/@alvenw/how-to-store-images-to-mongodb-with-node-js-fb3905c37e6d

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways to do it, I will probably do like this.

On the nodejs part, create a simple `express` server and combine with the package call `multer` to handling all the incoming file.

And on the flutter part, handle the image using a package call `image_picker` and sent it in a form data through `http`